# Is there a lightweight alternative to tracing-subscriber?

Tags: rust, rust-tracing

The [tracing-subscriber](https://crates.io/crates/tracing-subscriber) crate contains a ton of features and adds about 300k to my binary. I'm looking for a very lightweight alternative that only prints all the spans to std-out.

I assume that there is an API to implement for a completely custom subscriber but it doesn't seem very documented as everyone is basically using tracing-subscriber as is, or customizing that library.

Comment: Are you programming for embedded or WASM? If not, you probably don't need to optimize for binary size.

Comment: I'm programing for an envrionment with very limited resources where startup time is absolutely critical. tracing-sub adds about 30-40ms of additional latency In my tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement [`Subscriber`](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/trait.Subscriber.html) and call [`tracing::subscriber::set_global_default()`](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/subscriber/fn.set_global_default.html). This is fairly well documented.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Chayim Friedman suggestion i went ahead with the following implementation:

```
use std::env;

use std::{fmt, sync::atomic::AtomicUsize, write};

use std::fmt::Write;
use tracing::Level;
use tracing::{field::Visit, Id, Subscriber};
use tracing_core::Field;

pub struct StringVisitor<'a> {
    string: &'a mut String,
}
impl<'a> StringVisitor<'a> {
    pub(crate) fn new(string: &'a mut String) -> Self {
        StringVisitor { string }
    }
}

impl<'a> Visit for StringVisitor<'a> {
    fn record_debug(&mut self, field: &Field, value: &dyn fmt::Debug) {
        if field.name() == "message" {
            write!(self.string, "{value:?} ").unwrap();
        } else {
            write!(self.string, "{} = {:?}; ", field.name(), value).unwrap();
        }
    }
}

struct LogFilter {
    target: Option<String>,
    level: Option<Level>,
}

pub struct MinimalTracer {
    enabled: bool,
    filters: Vec<LogFilter>,
}

fn string_to_level(string: &str) -> Option<Level> {
    match string.to_lowercase().as_str() {
        "info" => Some(Level::INFO),
        "debug" => Some(Level::DEBUG),
        "warn" | "warning" => Some(Level::WARN),
        "trace" => Some(Level::TRACE),
        "error" => Some(Level::ERROR),
        _ => None,
    }
}

impl MinimalTracer {
    pub fn register() -> Result<(), tracing::subscriber::SetGlobalDefaultError> {
        let mut enabled = true;
        let mut filters: Vec<LogFilter> = Vec::with_capacity(10);
        if let Ok(env_value) = env::var("RUST_LOG") {
            for filter in env_value.split(',') {
                let mut target = Some(filter);
                let mut level = None;
                if let Some(equals_index) = target.unwrap().find('=') {
                    let (first, second) = filter.split_at(equals_index);
                    target = Some(first);
                    level = string_to_level(&second[1..])
                }
                let target_level = string_to_level(target.unwrap());

                if let Some(target_level) = target_level {
                    level = Some(target_level);
                    target = None;
                }

                filters.push(LogFilter {
                    target: target.map(|v| v.to_string()),
                    level,
                });
            }
        } else {
            enabled = false;
        }

        tracing::subscriber::set_global_default(MinimalTracer { enabled, filters })
    }
}

static AUTO_ID: AtomicUsize = AtomicUsize::new(1);

impl Subscriber for MinimalTracer {
    fn enabled(&self, metadata: &tracing::Metadata<'_>) -> bool {
        if self.enabled {
            if self.filters.is_empty() {
                return true;
            }

            let mut matches: bool;
            for filter in &self.filters {
                matches = true;
                if let Some(level) = filter.level {
                    if metadata.level() != &level {
                        matches = false;
                    }
                }
                if let Some(target) = &filter.target {
                    if !metadata.target().starts_with(target) {
                        matches = false;
                    }
                }
                if matches {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        false
    }

    fn new_span(&self, _span: &tracing_core::span::Attributes<'_>) -> tracing_core::span::Id {
        Id::from_u64(AUTO_ID.fetch_add(1, std::sync::atomic::Ordering::Relaxed) as u64)
    }

    fn record(&self, _span: &tracing_core::span::Id, _values: &tracing_core::span::Record<'_>) {}

    fn record_follows_from(
        &self,
        _span: &tracing_core::span::Id,
        _follows: &tracing_core::span::Id,
    ) {
    }

    fn event(&self, event: &tracing::Event<'_>) {
        let metadata = event.metadata();

        let level = metadata.level();
        let target = metadata.target();

        let mut text = String::new();

        let mut visitor = StringVisitor::new(&mut text);
        event.record(&mut visitor);

        println!("{level} {target}: {text}");
    }

    fn enter(&self, _span: &tracing_core::span::Id) {}

    fn exit(&self, _span: &tracing_core::span::Id) {}
}
```

Comment: I personally would add a timestamp to the output and likely hard-code the filters for the particular use-case, but this is a nice foundation for a simple subscriber.